# Comparing SVG Piechart values with database using selenium webdriver

Tags: svg, selenium-webdriver

I need to automate my website having several SVG elements.The chart displays values inside a tool tip  on mouse hover.So can i compare whether values in chart matches with database values using selenium WebDriver. How can i locate SVG elements using WebDriver.

Comment: Please, post chart element contents

Comment: Hi Alexander Petrovich, Page contains pie chart and line charts.Both charts get updated when user changes the menu on left side of page. Values from database will get reflected in charts on mouse hover when user changes menu links